# Error building projects on .Net Core after gacutil

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, gac

I recently install Visual Studio Community 2017 to study .Net Core and found an error in my first attempt to build the starter project (automatically generated).

[First error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHZvo.png)

Searching through StackOverflow I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876702/uwp-and-xamarin-builds-failing-with-no-output) answer and I executed the 2 commands described in the answer:

> gacutil -u Microsoft.Build

and

> gacutil -u Microsoft.Build.Framework

After this, my project started to have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdRqs.png) errors.

```
System.Object not defined

System.void not defined

System.String not defined

...
```

By looking the assemblies installed in my GAC, I see the difference [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waVRZ.png).

I just need to build my .Net Core solution, but now I have to fix the second problem to return and fix the first problem.

**PS: I Already reinstall VS Community 2017 and it did not fix the problem**